# Is it possible using SQL in SQL Server - Showing all records from Table A even if

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables like the following: the first table stores a list and used as the master list

Table A

```
 ImageId    ImageName
 ---------------------
 101        X-Ray
 102        MRI
 103        CTSCAN
```

My second table shows hospital reports for the above:

Table B

```
HospitalId Month  ImageId    NumberOfVisits
-------------------------------------------
111        1      101        20
111        1      102        30
222        1      101        21
```

Now I would like to create a query like following. I want to show  all from Table A in Table B even if the record from Table A does not exist in Table B

Table C

```
HospitalId Month   ImageName   NumberOfVisits
----------------------------------------------
111        1       X-Ray       20
111        1       MRI         30
111        1       CTSCAN       0
222        1       X-Ray       21
222        1       MRI          0
222        1       CTSCAN       0
```

I am trying to create a report or table to summarize the number of services a hospital in each month. I want to show 0 if there is no report for a month in hospital.

I tried the left join to make it but it did not help.

I tried the union query, joining but it does not work

```
SELECT        
    B.Hospitalid, A.ImageName, B.Month, B.NumberOfVisits
FROM          
    dbo.TableA A 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.TableB B ON A.ImageId = B.ImageId

UNION ALL 

SELECT        
    B.Hospitalid, A.ImageName, B.Month, B.NumberOfVisits
FROM          
    dbo.TableA A 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.TableB B ON A.ImageId = B.ImageId
WHERE
    A.ImageId & B.HospitalId NOT IN (SELECT A.ImageId&B.HospitalId 
                                     FROM dbo.TableA A 
                                     INNER JOIN dbo.TableB B ON A.ImageId = B.ImageId)
```

I want to show  all from Table A in Table B even if the record from Table A does not exist in Table B

```
HospitalId Month   ImageName   NumberOfVisits
---------------------------------------------
111        1       X-Ray       20
111        1       MRI         30
111        1       CTSCAN       0
222        1       X-Ray       21
222        1       MRI          0
222        1       CTSCAN       0
```

Comment: Use a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: need to cross join hospitals with images and months, and then left join to Table B..

Comment: left join show blank for hospitalid,moth, numberOfvisits for the imagename but i want it to be filled.

Comment: That is how left join works. When there is no match it still returns the main table rows but the columns in the table that didn't have a match are NULL. What else could they possibly be?

Comment: @Sean Lange Please read my requirement. I tried left join, cross join but it did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use cross join to get your images, hospitals and months.  Then left join TableB

```
with cte as (select     *
             from       (select distinct ImageId, ImageName from tableA) as a1
             cross join (select distinct HospitalId from tableB)         as b1
             cross join (select distinct month from tableB) as b2 )
select      cte.HospitalId
            , cte.Month
            , cte.ImageName
            , coalesce(tb.NumberOfVisits, 0) as NumberOfVisits
from        cte
left join   dbo.TableB as tb on  tb.HospitalId = cte.HospitalId
                             and tb.ImageId = cte.ImageId
                             and tb.Month = cte.Month
```